Content Security Policy for Embedded JS and dynamic scripts
I am using Webpack 4. I have included CSP headers in both the meta tag and web.config. Now, I want to add hashes for other inline scripts by removing ‘unsafe-inline’. However, when I run the code in the browser, Chrome generates different hash values each time. It appears that the script content changes dynamically, affecting the hashes. My goal is to manage these scripts and include their hash values in the web.config file.
i tried adding in web.config like below:
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
......
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self';script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'sha256-Fs/OtiEA4gYZFomNxVBaVDAlEf2fJSbeaRZXutwAySg=' 'sha256-dZEEz7IHI4iSaHbzXfMvvd4vIMiiEMJnYb/rCT7QiGc=' 'sha256-H9qtdbx53C00IwXC4D3NrA8ggCq0dIkFC4BdFcs6SDA=' 'sha256-A7wv/Ov4T4GDfOKluiqye57n5ZavTw1SIh555zRq3jM=' 'sha256-7Q6BJ8/QhOemNbDFrd21+1li3VFOqx7tCEre1SvrQeA=' 'strict-dynamic';"/>
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>

in index.html file i have EJS line, i want to create hash values for that:
        <script src="/gtag.js"></script>
    <script src="/exponea.js"></script>
    <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.webpackManifest %>
    <base href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.ext.baseHref %>">
    <script src="/cookiebot.js"></script>

